# Using API to download the dashboard rendered as PNG

Tags: rest-api, analytics-api

I'm trying to use the [Analytics Download API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_download_reference_resource.htm) to get a PNG of my dashboard, but I'm getting a resource not found error.

The command I'm using:

```
curl https://[my_organization-dev].my.salesforce.com/services/data/v55.0/analytics/download/dashboard/[dashboard_id].png -H "Authorization: Bearer [token]"
```

The response I'm getting:

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]%
```

I'm using the same ID I got from listing recently viewed dashboards, and I can use this ID for other dashboard-related API calls, so I am confident I'm using the correct ID.

I've also tried using this API to download a report png, which didn't work. Just to make sure, I've tried using the dashboard name instead of ID, which also didn't work.

I am using cURL to make requests, which has worked for all the other API calls I've tried so far.

Edit: I'm working on Salesforce Developer Edition as a proof of concept. I've enabled Slack for Salesforce and CRM Analytics in my "organization" and can use other API functions that require this, including other Analytics API functions.
I can download the dashboard image from the dashboard itself, but I'm looking for a way to do it through the API for automation purposes.

Using [this guide](https://www.asagarwal.com/how-to-find-out-the-edition-and-release-of-a-salesforce-instance/), I ensured that my sandbox organization is using API version 55.0, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Do you have Slack for Salesforce and CRM Analytics for Slack enabled in your org? See [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_download_reference_resource.htm)

Comment: Could you please add few more details here. I believe you can download the dashboard image through out-of-box- functionality?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've added some more information to the question, and addressed both those. Hopefully I'm not missing anything important!

Comment: @Cyare did you ever figure anything out on this? Hitting the same error when trying to download a dashboard PNG.

Comment: @cdwyer Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

To download data from widgets and lenses using the CRM Analytics user interface, Download CRM Analytics Data user permission needs to be granted. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_download.htm&type=5

It is worth it to check the experience from UI vs API.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and then noticed that [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_download_example_crma_dashboard_pdf.htm) says domain/analytics/download/dashboard/0FKB0000000xxxxxxx.pdf

I removed "services/data/v55.0/" from mine and now it works! So hopefully if you use https://[my_organization-dev].my.salesforce.com/analytics/download/dashboard/[dashboard_id].png, yours will work too.

[Update] I also had to pass a session id to my request